# Reading data SQL server database

Tags: sql-server

I have created an SQL server database and saved data using vb.net code.
How can I read that file's data, the way we do in Access?

Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using VB .Net to save data, you can use VB .Net to read that data as well.

This link can give you a brief guideline:

http://www.fryan0911.com/2009/05/vbnet-tutorial-sql-database-basics.html

On the other hand, if you just want to see what data is on your database, or manage your database (tables, relations, procedures....) you can use SQL Server Management Studio (google it, and you will be able to find a lot of material/download links), the express edition is free of charge:

Answer (score 0):

Create an account on the sql server (a sql login, or windows login, if you don't have one already).  In you VB application, create a new page and throw a gridview onto it.  click the little aarow thing and follow the insstructions

Comment: Does it mean if no account has been created, the database is open for everybody?